# Airflow ssh operator does not kill the running taks

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow to trigger tasks on a windows machine using ssh.

I am able to authenticate and then run a  python script on the windows machine itself.

However, when I mark the tasks as failed, the logs say about taking the poison pill, but when I log in in the window machine, the tasks is still running.

Do I need to supply any arguments to the SSHOperator, or did somebody encounter a similar error?